# "Field StageName does not exist" when creating a formula for Case Object

Tags: process-builder, formula, case

I'm trying to create a process that validates the Stage of the Case based on certain record types and I'm getting this crazy error:

[image]

```
     ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Escalated") &&
(
[Case].RecordType.DeveloperName ="Account_Closure_Form" || [Case].RecordType.DeveloperName 
="Create_A_Batch" || [Case].RecordType.DeveloperName ="Debit_or_EBT_Research_Form" || 
[Case].RecordType.DeveloperName ="Research_Fee_Reversal_Special_Request_Form" || 
[Case].RecordType.DeveloperName ="Manager_Review_Case" || [Case].RecordType.DeveloperName 
 ="Full_Card_Number_Request")
```

I'm trying to send an email notification if the Case stage is "escalated" and the Case Record Type falls into ANY of the following record types.

I did checked that the CaseStage was added in the Record Type Layouts.

Any idea on why this error is showing and how it could be solved ??

Comment: Also check what field you're actually trying to interact with on Case. `StageName` is a field on Opportunity. It sounds like you might want `Status` or some custom field you may have created on Case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice how all the other field paths begin with `[Case].`. You need to do the same with `StageName`, changing it to `[Case].StageName`. However, the `Case` object in fact [does not have this field](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_case.htm). If you had for example a custom `Opportunity__c` lookup you'd do `[Case].Opportunity__r.StageName`. Alternatively, if you wanted to filter on something like `Status` you would use `[Case].Status`.